# Type error related to generics depending on location of function

Tags: generics, f#

I created a pipe-able `ofType<'T>` function for sequences based on `Enumerable.OfType<'T>()`:

```
let ofType<'T> (sequence : _ seq) = sequence.OfType<'T>()
```

Using this within the same `.fsx` file works fine; it still does when I put it into a module:

```
module Seq =
    let ofType<'T> (sequence : _ seq) = sequence.OfType<'T>()
```

It stops working when I move it into another script file and (to be able to access it from elsewhere) wrap it in another top-level module:

```
module Prelude =
    open System.Linq

    module Seq =
        let ofType<'T> (sequence : _ seq) = sequence.OfType<'T>()
```

I reference this from my original script file, open the `Prelude` module and call the function like this:

```
let getXmlIncludes (xtype : Type) =
    xtype.GetCustomAttributes() |> Seq.ofType<XmlIncludeAttribute>
```

That causes `Seq.ofType<XmlIncludeAttribute>` to be marked as an error, with the message

```
error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Attribute> -> 'a    
> but given a
    Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Attribute> -> Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<XmlIncludeAttribute>    
The type 'obj' does not match the type 'Attribute'
```

The error remains the same when I move `ofType<'T>` directly into the `Prelude` module.

Why does this happen, and how can I make it not happen?

(I tried changing the `_ seq` type for the `sequence` parameter to `'TSeq seq`, which results in the ever-popular

```
warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'TSeq has been constrained to be type 'obj'.
```

but doesn't change anything about the error.)

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your error. Maybe you could provide a repo demonstrating the error.

Comment: Isn't the existing `Seq.cast` already a `Enumerable.OfType` in disguise ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht `OfType<T>` is the same as `.Where(x => x is typeof(T))`, e.g. filter by type. Follow my first link from the answer and you will see both `OfType` and `Cast` implementations on the same screen.

Comment: @V.B. yeah I mixed the two in my mind ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Enumerable.OfType<'T>()` is [not generic](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,897) with regards to input parameter. After changing `_ seq` to non-generic `IEnumerable` the error disappears.

```
open System
open System.Collections
open System.Reflection
open System.Xml.Serialization

module Prelude =
    open System.Linq
    module Seq =
        let inline ofType<'T> (sequence : IEnumerable) = sequence.OfType<'T>()

open Prelude
let getXmlIncludes (xtype : Type) =
    xtype.GetCustomAttributes() |> Seq.ofType<XmlIncludeAttribute>
```

In your original code `(sequence : _ seq)` is constrained to `seq<Attribute>`, but F# [does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203560/f-and-interface-covariance-what-to-do-specifically-seq-aka-ienumerable) [not](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/3830226-support-casting-f-flexible-types-to-covariant-ne) support type covariance and cannot work with `seq<XmlIncludeAttribute>` as if it was `seq<Attribute>`, even though `XmlIncludeAttribute` inherits `Attribute`. But even if F# had supported covariance, your example would have worked only for this particular case plus only for types that inherit from `Attribute`.

You could clearly see the error if you try to use your Seq extension with a different type:

```
let getIntsAsUints (list : List<int>) =
    list |> Seq.ofType<uint32>

Script.fsx(21,13): error FS0001: The type 'List<int>' is not compatible with the type 'seq<Attribute>'
```

Comment: Thanks; `.OfType<'T>()` working on non-generic `IEnumerable` was the thing I overlooked.