# In F#, what is the simplest method of upcasting a typed list to a seq<_>?

Tags: list, f#, ienumerable, upcasting

(Newbie question) In F#, what is the simplest method of upcasting a typed list to a seq<_> ?

I am working on interop with C# and trying to learn F#. I have specifically a list of movies defined as:

```
Movies: MovieInfo list option
```

which I would like to upcast to

```
 ItemsSource: seq<obj> option
```

So given Movies, how do I go to ItemsSource?

e.g., movies |>   ?????

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Not sure if it's the easiest, but `Seq.ofList` would do the job. If you need to have a cast, you can use `Seq.Cast`. `movies |> Seq.ofList |> Seq.cast<obj>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two small tasks here: (1) convert the list to a sequence, which is what you asked about, and (2) do it "inside" the `option`.

Converting a list to sequence is easy: `Seq.ofList`. Plus, if you need to cast the element type, use `Seq.cast`:

```
let movies: MovieInfo list = ...
let itemsSource = movies |> Seq.ofList |> Seq.cast
```

But that's not all: you don't have a naked list `MovieInfo list`, you have it inside an `option` - `MovieInfo list option`. And a way to apply a transformation to a value inside of an option is via `Option.map`:

```
let x = Some 3
let y = x |> Option.map ((+) 2)  // now, y = Some 5
```

So to combine all of the above:

```
let ItemsSource = Movies |> Option.map (Seq.ofList >> Seq.cast)
```

Answer (score 2):

Usage of `Seq.cast` have overhead of creating new enumerable, that wraps original, see [source](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/b831e4f4dbc85a0dc60fca2d60396bc1d0074232/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L643). Better to use casting

```ml
let movies : MovieInfo list = []
let moviesAsObj = movies :> seq<_> :?> seq<obj>
// and if it's inside `option`
let moviesOpt = Some movies
let moviesAsObjOpt = moviesOpt |> Option.map (fun m -> m :> seq<_> :?> obj)
```

Took idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4203635/10339675)